# iTunes Connect: App transfer specifics

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, itunes, app-store-connect

I'm currently planning the transfer of some apps from one iOS-Developer-Programm to another. Now Apple introduced the option to transfer the apps via 'Transfer App' in iTunes connect (more details in the [ITC FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/3.0.0.7.3.0.9.3.3.1.0.21.2.0.1.3.1))

Apple specifically says, that

> You cannot transfer iCloud enabled apps or apps using iCloud entitlements, Passbook IDs, certificates, or **notifications**.

**Q: Would it be possible to upload a new version with push-notifications disabled in the App-ID and then use the 'Transfer app'-utility?**

My reasoning goes thus: theoretically it should be possible to do this, once the push-notification capability is disabled. 
However, since this feature is quite new and Apple has posted barely any information on how it works (apart from this really short FAQ), I'd rather ask around before trying and failing miserably.

*So: does anyone have already experience with transferring apps that didn't stick to Apple's rules?*

Comment: Probably best to ask on Apple support forum or contact Apple directly as everyone will just be getting there sources from your link.

Comment: Yes, of course, I did that as well. Problem is, apparently Apple Support is swamped with requests right now (not surprising considering WWDC is still running), and I haven't received a reply yet. So, I thought I'd try it this way, hoping that someone experimented with the feature already.

Comment: Got any reply from support?